# Prometheus: Modifying metrics label value

Tags: prometheus

I want to modify the following label:

```
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/host/srv"}
```

to:

```
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/srv"}
```

How should I write `<relabel_config>`? I've read the documentation, but could not figure it out as there's no example whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself with the following:

```
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [mountpoint]
        regex: '(\/)(host\/?)(.*)'
        replacement: "${1}${3}"
        target_label: mountpoint
```